# Problema al obtener la url actual usando php

Tags: php

Buenas tengo el  siguiente error a la hora de obtener la url actual usando php
la url es la siguiente :

> `http://localhost/token.php?#access_token=EAALhZB1GcFMUBAIk7fEy1221212HjQUT6wb0NypHpKYRKRxcQVcKxmn56hn0RdZB6LO6qyppN1Jc7VBjcJITzOoKBT65dKZBgiyy55HNqdKuTAJSVnfgCwfdBBwe1rl0cUeksZAXcuG8cLJLwMYHQ8557bvVjhD2MTse3czS3o1c0jWmIqdWMYLJ63TYIIpFKK4DVm8a3LtH7sq2Ngz5QZDZD&expires_in=709385`

Como pueden observar la url tiene esta parte `?#access_token` el signo # impide obtener la url completa usando este método.

```
$urls = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 

echo $urls;
```

Lo que intento es obtener la url completa , solo consigo esta parte `http://localhost/token.php?`

Answer (score 1):

El problema es el signo del `gato #`, nunca se enviarán al servidor por que por lo regular se utiliza para anclas de la página del lado del cliente. Revisa esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7659177/4987172).

Comment: Entiendo pero me pregunto si es posible usando otro lenguaje junto a php para lograr obtener la url completa

Comment: podrias obtenerlo por medio de JS o cambiar el nombre de la variable

Comment: puedes darme algun ejemplo del codigo

Comment: eso depende de cómo lo quieres utilizar ¿Vas a pasarla por GET?